# Laravel: Auth, Session and Cookie

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel

I'm getting a bit confused over how Auth works in combination with sessions and cookies.

If a user logs in, then where is the information stored for keeping that user logged in? My Auth driver is "Eloquent", but that's only for Laravel to know where the user information is to attempt a login I presume?

I have a sessions table installed. But only storing information on an Auth user in the database wouldn't suffice. Therefore a cookie must be set to identify the user on the client machine. But I can't grasp what is stored where and how the inner workings of the auth system are.

And since I have a "Sessions" table, if I do

```
Session::push('foo', 'bar');
```

foo isn't saved in the sessions table. So is foo then saved in the $_SESSION php global or somewhere else? And if that's true, then is the "Sessions" table only for storing Auth information or is it used for other storing other information as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can tell Laravel how to store sessions in your `app/config/session.php` file.

Comment: In Laravel you can't access sessions via the $_SESSION super global (without major, ugly hacks).

Comment: I have a session table and the driver in the session config file. Now if I push something to the session, will it be stored in the database? There always only is one row in that table. So is everything stored in one row?

Comment: Use `Session::put()`

Comment: `push()` method pushes onto an array.  `put()` puts a new session.

Comment: So for every client making requests to your app a row in the session table is stored where the payload is updated with the information that is stored in the session?

Comment: You can use push, but if you want to push it onto an array it will be one row and you'll have to push it properly rather than resetting it.

Comment: But how does auth work under the hood? Does it set a cookie with an unique identifier which checks the session table if there is a row which has the same identifier?

Comment: If you want to know how it all works under the hood, check out `Illuminate\Auth`